# Set CALayer Gradient Background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add a gradient to a CALayer I have created. I can set the background colour of the CALayer with the following:

```
self.colorLayer = [CALayer layer];
[self.colorLayer setBackgroundColor:color.CGColor]; 
[self.colorView setWantsLayer:YES]; 
[self.colorView setLayer:self.colorLayer];
```

I've looked around with no success (surprisingly I thought this would have been answered many times).

I have made a gradient with:

```
NSGradient *gradient = 
    [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor orangeColor] 
        endingColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
```

But can't add it to my CALayer or add an angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[NSColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[NSColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
    gradient.frame = self.colorView.bounds;
    [self.colorView setLayer:gradient];
    [self.colorView setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Comment: just thought i'd put the code in once it worked, i wasn't sure what to do with 'Assign a CAGradientLayer to its layer property?'

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to add a gradient to a CALayer, because you can use a CAGradientLayer instead.

Comment: ok, so i have a new viewController with xib file which i initialise with  self.gradientView = [[GradView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GradView" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.gradientView.view];
    self.gradientView.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.view).bounds;

Comment: how could i add the background colour of this view to be a gradient?

Comment: Assign a CAGradientLayer to its `layer` property?

Comment: CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[NSColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[NSColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
    [self.gradientView.view.layer addSublayer:gradient];????

Comment: Your last line should be `self.gradientView.layer = gradient;` since, as @matt said, you can set the view's layer (its root layer can simply be replaced - no need to add your gradient layer as a sublayer).

Comment: this doesn't work.  How can I just set the background of NSViewController to a gradient? Really difficult to find anything on this, has no one ever done it?

Comment: I just want to set either a customView, or NSViewController xib background colour to a gradient.  I'm looking for anyway to set a gradient to any kind of view

Comment: Try with the NSView, i have created a NSView in storyboard, linked it up.  I can then easily set the background colour of this view using self.colorLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [self.colorLayer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor].CGColor];
    [self.colorView setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self.colorView setLayer:self.colorLayer];      Now instead of setting the  background colour to a flat colour i want a gradient instead.  I've tried various ways to add a CAGradientLayer to my colorView (colourView and colorLayer are different)

Comment: basically how can i get a gradient on anything? But try NSView as nothing seems to work

Comment: CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[NSColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[NSColor greenColor] CGColor], nil];
    gradient.frame = self.colorView.bounds;
    [self.colorView setLayer:gradient];    this doesn't work and nothing else seems to

Comment: Why? Does `CAGradientLayer` support `path`?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30901488/7210344)

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [NSColor.hlpMarineBlue, NSColor.hlpDarkishBlue, NSColor.hlpOceanBlue]
    gradient.frame = self.backgroundView.bounds;
    self.colorView.layer = gradient
    self.colorView.wantsLayer = true
```

Answer (score 0):

//To Use:

```
guard let firstColot: NSColor = NSColor(hexString: HexColorCode.code.leftMenuFirstColor.rawValue) else {return}
guard let secondColor: NSColor = NSColor(hexString: HexColorCode.code.leftMenuSecondColor.rawValue) else {return}
    
leftMenuBgView.gradient(fillView: leftMenuBgView,
                            withGradientFromColors: [firstColot, secondColor])



extension NSView {

func gradient(fillView view: NSView, withGradientFromColors colors: Array<NSColor>) {
    self.wantsLayer = true
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
    let color1 = colors[0].cgColor
    let color2 = colors[1].cgColor
    gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    self.layer?.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
  }
}
```