# How to add gradient colour to CALayer()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
let bottomBorder = CALayer()
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.viewShadowGray().cgColor
bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 1, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 1)
view.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

How to modify this to add gradient to it such that it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876811/set-calayer-gradient-background

Comment: You are looking for `CAGradientLayer`, a subclass of `CALayer` done for that. Also, that depending on your final goal, that gradient could be interpreted as a inner/outer shadow and be done without `CAGradientLayer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Apply Gradient to background view of iOS Swift App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CAGradientLayer`:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - 1, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 1)
gradientLayer.colors = [
    UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor,
    UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor
]
view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Adjust the gradients colors to you needs.