# How to compose UIButton from CAGradientLayers and CAShapeLayers?

Tags: ios, uikit, cagradientlayer

I'd like to recreate a bevel-effect circular `UIButton` subclass, as pictured below (but with a user-chosen base color). I am confused on how to set the bounds for a CAGradientLayer / masking CAShapeLayer.

[image: Goal1]

I figured to compose this of several `CAShapeLayers` as I would in SwiftUI. This renders as desired (sans-gradients).

[image: CAShapeLayers]

However, when masking a `CAGradientLayer` with a previously-rendered `CAShapeLayer`, the gradient is not drawn visibly.

[image: CAGradientLayer3]

I assume my error is related to bounds/frame setting. When I move the sublayer additions to `layoutSubviews()`, part of the gradient ring is rendered. Also, the user-color circle obeys constraints set by a parent VC, but the other layers do not.

[image: layoutSubviews]

I've read several posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721363/mask-uiview-with-uibezierpath-stroke-only/57525960#57525960) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733966/applying-a-gradient-to-cashapelayer), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876811/set-calayer-gradient-background), [4](http://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/drawing-using-cashapelayer-in-ios-9a6c83de7eb2)) on applying a `CAShapeLayer` as a mask to a `CAGradientLayer`, but am failing to understand how to properly set frames for these multiple layers.

```swift
extension BeveledButton {
    
    /// Draws yellow ring in desired location
    func makeEmbossmentRingAsShapeLayer()  -> CAShapeLayer {
        let pathFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: insetBevel, dy: insetBevel)
        let path = CGPath.circleStroked(width: bevelRingWidth, inFrame: pathFrame)
        
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        return shape
    }
    
    /// Does not draw gradient (visibly) where yellow ring was
    func makeEmbossmentRingAsGradientLayer()  -> CAGradientLayer {
        let pathFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: insetBevel, dy: insetBevel)
        let path = CGPath.circleStroked(width: bevelRingWidth, inFrame: frame)
        
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path
        mask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        mask.lineWidth = 4
        mask.frame = pathFrame
        
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer(colors: [UIColor.orange, UIColor.green], in: pathFrame)
        gradient.frame = pathFrame
        gradient.mask = mask
        return gradient
    }
}
```

```swift
extension CGPath {
    
    static func circle(inFrame: CGRect) -> CGPath {
        CGPath(ellipseIn: inFrame, transform: nil)
    }
    
    static func circleStroked(width: CGFloat, inFrame: CGRect) -> CGPath {
        var path = CGPath(ellipseIn: inFrame, transform: nil)
        path = path.copy(strokingWithWidth: width, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0)
        return path
    }
}

extension CAGradientLayer {
    
    convenience init(colors: [UIColor], in frame: CGRect) {
        self.init()
        self.colors = colors.map(\.cgColor)
        self.frame = frame
    }
}
```

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

class BeveledButton: UIButton {
    
    weak var userColor: CurrentValueSubject<UIColor,Never>?
    private var updates: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    private lazy var outerRing: CAShapeLayer = makeOuterRing()
    private lazy var innerReflection: CAShapeLayer = makeReflectionCircle()
    private lazy var userColorCircle: CAShapeLayer = makeUserColorCircle()
    private lazy var embossmentRing: CAGradientLayer = makeEmbossmentRingAsGradientLayer()
    //    private lazy var embossmentRing: CAShapeLayer = makeEmbossmentRingAsShapeLayer()
    
    init(frame: CGRect, userColor: CurrentValueSubject<UIColor,Never>) {
        self.userColor = userColor
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupRings()
        updateUserColor(userColor)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("") }
    
    private let outerRingWidth: CGFloat = 2.5
    private let inset: CGFloat = 3
    private let insetReflection: CGFloat = 5
    private lazy var insetBevel: CGFloat = inset + 1
    private let bevelRingWidth: CGFloat = 2
}


private extension BeveledButton {
    
    func setupRings() {
        layer.addSublayer(outerRing)
        layer.addSublayer(userColorCircle)
        layer.addSublayer(innerReflection)
        layer.addSublayer(embossmentRing)
    }
    
    func makeOuterRing() -> CAShapeLayer {
        let path = CGPath.circle(inFrame: frame)
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        shape.lineWidth = outerRingWidth
        shape.path = path
        return shape
    }
    
    func makeUserColorCircle()  -> CAShapeLayer {
        let pathFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
        let path = CGPath.circle(inFrame: pathFrame)
        
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = userColor?.value.cgColor
        return shape
    }
    
    func makeReflectionCircle()  -> CAShapeLayer {
        let pathFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: insetReflection, dy: insetReflection)
        let path = CGPath.circle(inFrame: pathFrame)
        
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor.copy(alpha: 0.4)
        return shape
    }
    
    func updateUserColor(_ userColor: CurrentValueSubject<UIColor,Never>) {
        updates = userColor.sink { [weak self] color in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self?.userColorCircle.fillColor = color.cgColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track...

The idea is to add **4** sublayers:

1. "outer" `CAShapeLayer`
2. "ring" `CAShapeLayer`
3. "bevel" `CAGradientLayer` with `CAShapeLayer` mask
4. "inner" `CAGradientLayer` with `CAShapeLayer` mask

Inset the frame of each layer by the width of the previous layer, so:

- rect = bounds
- outer layer frame will be rect
- inset rect by "outer width"
- ring layer frame will be that inset rect
- inset rect by "ring width"
- bevel layer frame will be that inset rect
- inset rect by "bevel width"
- inner layer frame will be that inset rect

So `layoutSubviews` will look something like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    var pth: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    var frameRect: CGRect = .zero
    var pathRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    frameRect = bounds
    
    outerLayer.frame = frameRect
    pathRect.size = frameRect.size
    pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
    outerLayer.path = pth.cgPath
    
    frameRect = frameRect.insetBy(dx: outerWidth, dy: outerWidth)
    
    ringLayer.frame = frameRect
    pathRect.size = frameRect.size
    pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
    ringLayer.path = pth.cgPath
    
    frameRect = frameRect.insetBy(dx: ringWidth, dy: ringWidth)
    
    bevelGradLayer.frame = frameRect
    pathRect.size = frameRect.size
    pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
    bevelLayerMask.path = pth.cgPath
    
    frameRect = frameRect.insetBy(dx: bevelWidth, dy: bevelWidth)
    
    innerGradLayer.frame = frameRect
    pathRect.size = frameRect.size
    pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
    innerLayerMask.path = pth.cgPath
    
}
```

In the code you posted, you are using `extension` to try and segment the code functions... that *can* be helpful, but it can also make things more complicated, and can make it a little difficult to follow the flow - particularly when elements need to be related.

Here is a version of what you're going for... note that it is `@IBDesignable` with various user-available `@IBInspectable` properties, so you can see it in IB / Storyboard (if desired):

```
@IBDesignable
class BevelButton: UIButton {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var outerColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            outerLayer.fillColor = outerColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var ringColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            ringLayer.fillColor = ringColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var startColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            bevelGradLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
            innerGradLayer.colors = [endColor.cgColor, startColor.cgColor]
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var endColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet {
            bevelGradLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
            innerGradLayer.colors = [endColor.cgColor, startColor.cgColor]
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var outerWidth: CGFloat = 6

    @IBInspectable
    var ringWidth: CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable
    var bevelWidth: CGFloat = 6
    
    private let outerLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let ringLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let innerLayerMask = CAShapeLayer()
    private let innerGradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    private let bevelLayerMask = CAShapeLayer()
    private let bevelGradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        layer.addSublayer(outerLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(ringLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(bevelGradLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(innerGradLayer)
        
        bevelGradLayer.mask = bevelLayerMask
        innerGradLayer.mask = innerLayerMask
        
        bevelLayerMask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        innerLayerMask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
        outerLayer.fillColor = outerColor.cgColor
        ringLayer.fillColor = ringColor.cgColor
        
        bevelGradLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        innerGradLayer.colors = [endColor.cgColor, startColor.cgColor]
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var pth: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        var frameRect: CGRect = .zero
        var pathRect: CGRect = .zero
        
        frameRect = bounds
        
        outerLayer.frame = frameRect
        pathRect.size = frameRect.size
        pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
        outerLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        frameRect = frameRect.insetBy(dx: outerWidth, dy: outerWidth)
        
        ringLayer.frame = frameRect
        pathRect.size = frameRect.size
        pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
        ringLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        
        frameRect = frameRect.insetBy(dx: ringWidth, dy: ringWidth)
        
        bevelGradLayer.frame = frameRect
        pathRect.size = frameRect.size
        pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
        bevelLayerMask.path = pth.cgPath
        
        frameRect = frameRect.insetBy(dx: bevelWidth, dy: bevelWidth)
        
        innerGradLayer.frame = frameRect
        pathRect.size = frameRect.size
        pth = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: pathRect)
        innerLayerMask.path = pth.cgPath
        
    }
    
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get {
            return super.isHighlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                innerGradLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
                bevelGradLayer.colors = [endColor.cgColor, startColor.cgColor]
            } else {
                bevelGradLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
                innerGradLayer.colors = [endColor.cgColor, startColor.cgColor]
            }
            super.isHighlighted = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how it looks (with default properties) in Storyboard:

[image]

Here's the `IBInspectable` properties panel:

[image]

And, at run-time, default state:

[image]

and Highlighted state (with the gradients flipped vertically):

[image]